# Transpose list of lists

Tags: python, list, transpose

Let's take:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
r = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

and not

```
r = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 546, accepted):

Python 3:

```py
# short circuits at shortest nested list if table is jagged:
list(map(list, zip(*l)))

# discards no data if jagged and fills short nested lists with None
list(map(list, itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=None)))
```

Python 2:

```py
map(list, zip(*l))
```

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Explanation:

There are two things we need to know to understand what's going on:

1. The signature of [zip](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip): `zip(*iterables)` This means `zip` expects an arbitrary number of arguments each of which must be iterable. E.g. `zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])`.
2. [Unpacked argument lists](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists): Given a sequence of arguments `args`, `f(*args)` will call `f` such that each element in `args` is a separate positional argument of `f`.
3. `itertools.zip_longest` does not discard any data if the number of elements of the nested lists are not the same (homogenous), and instead fills in the shorter nested lists *then* zips them up.

Coming back to the input from the question `l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, `zip(*l)` would be equivalent to `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])`. The rest is just making sure the result is a list of lists instead of a list of tuples.

Comment: Beware: if `l` is not evenly sized (say, some rows are shorter than others), `zip` will _not_ compensate for it and instead chop away rows from the output. So `l=[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]` gives you `[[1,3,5]]`.

Comment: The `itertools` function `zip_longest()` works with uneven lists. See [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: An explanation in answer would be nice :)

Comment: I think even `list(zip(*l))` works correctly in Python 3.

Comment: @Stefano It works (as does `zip(*l)` in Python 2), but you get a list of tuples, not a list of lists. Of course, `list(list(it))` is always the same thing as `list(it)`.

Comment: Simpler version that worked for me is. `list(itertools.zip_longest(*data))`
the `*` modifier effectively converts zip to extract, reversing the operation of zip..

Comment: I don't know if this worked back then, but a simpler way would be list(zip(*l))

Comment: @JimJam This works, but it doesn't fulfill the requirements. OP wanted a list of lists, not a list of tuples. Hence map(list, ...) :)

Comment: @BorisChurzin I finally added an explanation to my answer :) Apologies for taking so long.

Answer (score 108):

Equivalently to Jena's solution:

```
>>> l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(*l)]
... [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: As list comprehension is now preferred to `map()`, this solution is the one which is the most in the Python spirit...

Answer (score 85):

One way to do it is with [NumPy transpose](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html). For a list, a:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(l).T.tolist()
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Or another one without zip (python < 3):

```
>>> map(list, map(None, *l))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Or for python >= 3:

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: list(x), *l))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Love your second one -- I didn't realize `map` could do that. Here's a slight refinement that doesn't require 2 calls, though: `map(lambda *a: list(a), *l)`

Comment: Shouldnt this be a better answer as it takes care of uneven lists?

Comment: `map(None, ...)` doesn't seem to work for Py3. The generator is created but `next()` raises an error immediately: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Lee D please can you explain how the code returns expected data --> map(lambda *a: list(a), *l)

Comment: The numpy solution does not do jagged lists.

Comment: The numpy solution is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. One should not import numpy just for this task.

Answer (score 29):

just for fun, valid rectangles and assuming that m[0] exists

```
>>> m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [[row[i] for row in m] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for and couldn't get my head around. Still @jena's solution is really short

Comment: Yeah, it took a few tires to get this right. Okay, many tries.

Comment: Still isn't quite right -- this only happens to work when the dimensions are square! It should be: `[[j[i] for j in l] for i in range(len(l[0]))]`. Of course, you have to be sure that list `l` is not empty.

Comment: @LeeD still doesn't work for me on jena's example l=[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]

Comment: @hobs That was badp's example, responding to jena. However, I'm not sure it makes sense to me. IMO, transposition implies a rectangular matrix -- when represented as a list of lists, that means all the internal lists must be the same length. What result would you want as the "transposition" of this example?

Comment: @LeeD [[1,3,5],[2,4]]. I hear you, but transposition of a sparse matrix should be the same as transposition of a fully-populated matrix (or the enveloping rectangular matrix). The holes should remain holes, or filled with `NaN`s, if required to maintain the low level data structure. If the foreshortened row for badp's example were in the middle instead of the end, you'd have to use `NaN`s to maintain the sequence of sequences data structure, but not if you converted it to something that allows sparesness (like a `dict` of `dict`s or `scipy.sparse` matrix).

Comment: @badp, perhaps you could pad your matrix with `None`s or `NaN`s so that jena's approach would work.

Comment: matchew Please change that `len(l)` to `len(l[0])` as @LeeD suggests.

Answer (score 28):

Methods 1 and 2 work in Python 2 or 3, and they work on **ragged, rectangular** 2D lists. That means the inner lists do not need to have the same lengths as each other (ragged) or as the outer lists (rectangular). The other methods, well, it's complicated.

### the setup

```
import itertools
import six

list_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3], [7,8,9]]
```

---

### method 1 — `map()`, `zip_longest()`

```
>>> list(map(list, six.moves.zip_longest(*list_list, fillvalue='-')))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], ['-', 6.1, '-'], ['-', 6.2, '-'], ['-', 6.3, '-']]
```

`six.moves.zip_longest()` becomes

- [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2
- [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3

The default fillvalue is `None`. Thanks to @jena's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/673991), where `map()` is changing the inner tuples to lists. Here it is turning iterators into lists. Thanks to @Oregano's and @badp's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/673991).

In Python 3, pass the result through `list()` to get the same 2D list as method 2.

---

### method 2 — list comprehension, `zip_longest()`

```
>>> [list(row) for row in six.moves.zip_longest(*list_list, fillvalue='-')]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], ['-', 6.1, '-'], ['-', 6.2, '-'], ['-', 6.3, '-']]
```

The [@inspectorG4dget alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473742/673991).

---

### method 3 — `map()` of `map()` — *broken in Python 3.6*

```
>>> map(list, map(None, *list_list))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [None, 6.1, None], [None, 6.2, None], [None, 6.3, None]]
```

This extraordinarily compact [@SiggyF second alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473727/673991) works with ragged 2D lists, unlike his first code which uses numpy to transpose and pass through ragged lists. But None has to be the fill value. (No, the None passed to the inner map() is not the fill value. It means there is no function to process each column. The columns are just passed through to the outer map() which converts them from tuples to lists.)

Somewhere in Python 3, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) stopped putting up with all this abuse: the first parameter cannot be None, and ragged iterators are just truncated to the shortest. The other methods still work because this only applies to the inner map().

---

### method 4 — `map()` of `map()` revisited

```
>>> list(map(list, map(lambda *args: args, *list_list)))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]   // Python 2.7
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [None, 6.1, None], [None, 6.2, None], [None, 6.3, None]] // 3.6+
```

Alas the ragged rows do NOT become ragged columns in Python 3, they are just truncated. Boo hoo progress.

Answer (score 9):

## Three options to choose from:

#### 1. Map with Zip

```
solution1 = map(list, zip(*l))
```

#### 2. List Comprehension

```
solution2 = [list(i) for i in zip(*l)]
```

#### 3. For Loop Appending

```
solution3 = []
for i in zip(*l):
    solution3.append((list(i)))
```

#### And to view the results:

```
print(*solution1)
print(*solution2)
print(*solution3)

# [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
r = list(map(list, np.transpose(l)))
```

Comment: Alternative: `np.transpose(l).tolist()`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but here's a solution using nested while loops:

```
def transpose(lst):
    newlist = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        j = 0
        colvec = []
        while j < len(lst):
            colvec.append(lst[j][i])
            j = j + 1
        newlist.append(colvec)
        i = i + 1
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

`more_itertools.unzip()` is easy to read, and it also works with generators.

```
import more_itertools
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
r = more_itertools.unzip(l) # a tuple of generators.
r = list(map(list, r))      # a list of lists
```

or equivalently

```
import more_itertools
l = more_itertools.chunked(range(1,10), 3)
r = more_itertools.unzip(l) # a tuple of generators.
r = list(map(list, r))      # a list of lists
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,3]]
    
rows = len(matrix)
cols = len(matrix[0])

transposed = []
while len(transposed) < cols:
    transposed.append([])
    while len(transposed[-1]) < rows:
        transposed[-1].append(0)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        transposed[j][i] = matrix[i][j]

for i in transposed:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way for square matrix. No numpy, nor itertools, use (effective) in-place elements exchange.

```
def transpose(m):
    for i in range(1, len(m)):
        for j in range(i):
            m[i][j], m[j][i] = m[j][i], m[i][j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: If you then want to make them all into dicts.

```
In [1]: l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   ...: fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Peach",]
   ...: [dict(zip(fruits, j)) for j in [list(i) for i in zip(*l)]]
Out[1]:
[{'Apple': 1, 'Pear': 4, 'Peach': 7},
 {'Apple': 2, 'Pear': 5, 'Peach': 8},
 {'Apple': 3, 'Pear': 6, 'Peach': 9}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for transposing a list of lists that is not necessarily square:

```
maxCol = len(l[0])
for row in l:
    rowLength = len(row)
    if rowLength > maxCol:
        maxCol = rowLength
lTrans = []
for colIndex in range(maxCol):
    lTrans.append([])
    for row in l:
        if colIndex < len(row):
            lTrans[colIndex].append(row[colIndex])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    #Import functions from library
    from numpy import size, array
    #Transpose a 2D list
    def transpose_list_2d(list_in_mat):
        list_out_mat = []
        array_in_mat = array(list_in_mat)
        array_out_mat = array_in_mat.T
        nb_lines = size(array_out_mat, 0)
        for i_line_out in range(0, nb_lines):
            array_out_line = array_out_mat[i_line_out]
            list_out_line = list(array_out_line)
            list_out_mat.append(list_out_line)
        return list_out_mat
```