# Python 2D list slice

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

I looked around and could not find anything this specific, so here goes:

I have a list of lists:

```
S = [[3,4],[6,7],[10,12]]
```

and I would like to add the 0th index of the ith index element and on to the end of another list:

```
R = [5,6,7]
```

Normally with a 1D list I could say:

```
R = R + S[i:]
```

and take all of the elements from the ith index on, but I want the 0th index of the ith index of a 2D S. If we started at i = 1 I would end up with:

```
R = [5,6,7,6,10]
```

Also, I don't want to use for loops I want a list slice method that will work (if there is one) because it needs to be within a certain bound.

Comment: "because it needs to be within a certain bound" - what do you mean by that? It's not clear what sorts of bounds would be violated by a for loop, but not violated by slicing.

Comment: If you're working a lot with nested lists standing in for multidimensional arrays, consider `numpy`.

Comment: @user2357112 : I have sample code that is using the 1D method of just adding the sliced part of S[i:] to the end of R, so I assume that using a method similar to that will maintain the bounds needed. Also, as I learn some cleaner python style code I was wondering if there is a way to do it this way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : This is part of an assignment which can only use built-in libraries so numpy is out, otherwise I would definitely use it.

Comment: @Roklobster if this is an assignment, shouldn't you be doing it yourself?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : This is actually such a small portion of the assignment, and when I came across either using slices or using a for loop, I was wondering whether or not I could do it. If I were lazy I could have easily just kept my answer as I had it with: 

s = [S[i][0] for i in range(len(S))]
R = R + s

But I'm curious if there is a cleaner way using a slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip` to transpose the matrix:

```
>>> S
[[3, 4], [6, 7], [10, 12]]
>>> zip(*S)
[(3, 6, 10), (4, 7, 12)]
```

Then slice the transposition:

```
>>> j=0
>>> i=1
>>> zip(*S)[j][i:]
(6, 10)
```

A tuple is iterable, so concatenation will work with a list:

```
>>> R = [5,6,7]
>>> R+=zip(*S)[j][i:]
>>> R
[5, 6, 7, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, `numpy` will do the trick for you:

```
import numpy as np
# Create two arrays
S = np.asarray([[3,4],[6,7],[10,12]])
R = np.asarray([5, 6, 7])
# Slice the S array
i = 1
sliced_S = S[i:, 0]
# Concatenate the arrays
R = np.concatenate((R, sliced_S))
```

Have a look at `numpy`'s impressive [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) and [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) in particular.

Comment: As I told @jonrsharpe, I can only use built in libraries because it is being tested on a cs department cluster, and I can't be sure numpy is usable.

Comment: In case of homework, we don't tend to provide solutions but rather tips: Have a look at the `zip` function and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17037588/1150961 in particular.

Comment: Till, I'm not really looking for a homework solution as much as a best practice, but this is a solid way of doing it.