# compare elements of list to elements of list of lists and conditionally create new lists

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x, filter

It is about financial data. I have a list of the 70% percentiles of return data at 72 dates:

```
list = [0.11,0.12,...,0.125]
```

Furthermore I have a list of lists which contains the 72 returns at the different dates for 500 companies (= 500 lists and 72 entries per list):

```
list_of_lists = [[0.09,0.08,...,0.15],...,[0.1,0.34,...,0.01]]
```

What I want to do now is compare the first entry of my list (`0.11`) to all the entries in my first list in the list of lists. If the entry in the first list exceeds the `0.11` threshold (so in this case the `0.15` above) I want to add this number to a new list. Then I want to do the same with the second entry in `list` (`0.12`) and the second list in `list_of_lists`. In the end I basically want to obtain 72 lists (or a new list of lists) which contain the returns that are above the respective 70% percentile.

Comment: You say *500 lists and 72 entries per list*, shouldn't this by *72 lists and 500 entries per list*?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would definitely suggest looking into using a library like e.g. [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with list comprehension I think:

```
thresholds = [0.11,0.12,0.125]
quotes = [[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.1,0.34,0.01]]
[filter(lambda x: x > thresholds[idx],qts) for idx,qts in enumerate(quotes)]
```

I made some real lists out of the given ones (omitting the `...`) such that this is an example that compiles.

The list comprehension works as follows: we iterate over the `qts` from `quotes` (and also obtain the corresponding index `idx`, which is used to obtain the threshold). Next we perform a `filter` operation on the `qts` and only allow elements that are larger than the `threshold[idx]` (the threshold for that timestamp).

Running this with `python` gives:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> thresholds = [0.11,0.12,0.125]
>>> quotes = [[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.1,0.34,0.01]]
>>> [filter(lambda x: x > thresholds[idx],qts) for idx,qts in enumerate(quotes)]
[[0.15], [0.15], [0.34]]
```

which seems to be what you want.

**EDIT** In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), this should work as well, although the filter is "delayed":

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> thresholds = [0.11,0.12,0.125]
>>> quotes = [[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.09,0.08,0.15],[0.1,0.34,0.01]]
>>> res=[filter(lambda x: x > thresholds[idx],qts) for idx,qts in enumerate(quotes)]
>>> res[0]
<filter object at 0x7f0d3fbc2be0>
>>> list(res[0])
[0.15]
```

If you want to *materialize* the lists straight away, you can slightly alter the list comprehension to:

```
[list(filter(lambda x: x > thresholds[idx],qts)) for idx,qts in enumerate(quotes)]
```

Which results in:

```
>>> [list(filter(lambda x: x > thresholds[idx],qts)) for idx,qts in enumerate(quotes)]
[[0.15], [0.15], [0.34]]
```

Comment: How would I apply this in python 3? I get a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: @AlexanderEser: I do not get this error, see updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 500 lists of 72 values and 72 threshold values. You want to compare the *n*<sup>th</sup> value of *each* list with the *n*<sup>th</sup> value of your list of thresholds. In other words, you want to proceed column-wise. It's easiest to first [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) `list_of_lists` using [this one cool trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037588/1523776), so that each column in `list_of_lists` becomes a row:

```
transposed = zip(*list_of_lists)
```

Now we can work with rows. Pair each number in your list of thresholds with its corresponding row in `transposed`.

```
lists_with_thresholds = zip(list, transposed)
```

Each item in `lists_with_thresholds` is a pair containing a cutoff point and the values to which we want to compare it. The ducks are lined up in a row; we just have to find the values in the second part of the pair which exceed the corresponding cutoff point.

```
result = []
for threshold, values in lists_with_thresholds:
    values_over_threshold = []
    for x in values:
        if x > threshold:
            values_over_threshold.append(x)
    result.append(values_over_threshold)
```

Or, squishing the nested `for` loops up into a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [[x for x in values if x > threshold]
          for threshold, values in zip(list, zip(*list_of_lists))]
```

These two versions are exactly equivalent - they compile into the same byte code, for all intents and purposes - but I like the list comprehension better because it's shorter and it has a more functional feel.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
new_list = []
for i in lists_of_lists:
    for j in i:
        if j > list[0]:
            new_list.append(j)
```

Comment: Although I think this works, it's a but *un-pythonic* to call list modifiers. That's why they invented list comprehension. +1 nevertheless ;).

Comment: OP wants the elements of the sublists which are greater than the _corresponding_ element of `list`, not `list[0]`. Also, this will produce a flat list whereas OP wants a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks! I did it like this since I knew there would be plenty of list comprehension answers, and for beginners list comp is harder to read (at least for me it was). And I guess misunderstood the OP....

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
list = [4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_of_lists = [[6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6, 3, 8, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 6]]

above = [[ret for i, ret in enumerate(lst) if ret > list[i]] for lst in list_of_lists]
```

> [[6, 3, 7], [6, 8], [3, 7, 6]]

This will remove all entries in your lists in `list_of_lists` that are less or equal to the corresponding element of `list`.

Comment: OP wants the elements of the sublists which are greater than the _corresponding_ element of `list`.

Comment: Alright, fixed that. I think that wasn't totally clear from the question.