# How to flatten a dictionary into a tuple of two lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, flatten

Now I have a dictionary,

```
{2.9: [0.66], 3.3: [0.82, 0.48]}
```

and I want to flatten it to a tuple consisting of two lists:

```
([3.3, 3.3, 2.9], [0.82, 0.48, 0.66])
```

`3.3` appears twice because there were two elements in the corresponding dictionary entry.

How do I do it?

Comment: Where's the second 3.3 coming from?

Comment: There are two elements in the list corresbonding to 3.3, so each of the element has to match with 3.3 in the flattened tuple.

Comment: He is expanding it. So think: `{2.9: 0.66, 3.3: 0.82, 3.3:0.48}` (if that were possible)

Comment: @Goodies, maybe He is actually a she ;)

Answer (score 7):

If tuple of tuples is ok, it's slightly simpler

```
>>> D = {2.9: [0.66], 3.3: [0.82, 0.48]}
>>> tuple(zip(*((k, v) for k in D for v in D[k])))
((3.3, 3.3, 2.9), (0.82, 0.48, 0.66))
```

If you really need lists

```
>>> tuple(map(list, zip(*((k, v) for k in D for v in D[k]))))
([3.3, 3.3, 2.9], [0.82, 0.48, 0.66])
```

My variation of @Steven's and @Padraic's answers. (I avoid using `dict.items` because it's behaviour is so different between Python2 and Python3)

```
keys, vals = result = [], []
for k in D:
    v = D[k]
    vals += v
    keys += [k] * len(v)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {2.9: [0.66], 3.3: [0.82, 0.48]}
```

First let's distribute the two keys of the dictionary into a list of tuples:

```
>>> ts = [(k, x) for k, l in d.items() for x in l]
>>> ts
[(3.3, 0.82), (3.3, 0.48), (2.9, 0.66)]
```

I'm using a two-level list comprehension, which is syntactic sugar for the equivalent nested loop.

Then you can [transpose the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037566/transpose-a-matrix-in-python).

```
>>> result = zip(*ts)
>>> list(result)
[(3.3, 3.3, 2.9), (0.82, 0.48, 0.66)]
```

Or as a single expression, using a lazy generator expression instead of a list comprehension:

```
result = zip(*((k, x) for k, l in d.items() for x in l))
```

Comment: Minor nit:  OP wants a tuple of lists, not a list of tuples.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that it's likely OP doesn't mind whether it's a tuple or a list :)

Answer (score 2):

A variation of Stevens answer using extend as opposed to append as the dict keys are immutable so it is safe to just multiply.

```
d = {2.9: [0.66], 3.3: [0.82, 0.48]}

keys, vals = result = [], []
for k, v in d.items():
    vals.extend(v)
    keys.extend([k] * len(v))
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is John La Rooy's one-liner using `map`, `zip`, and a generator expression.  Here is a simplistic alternative:

```
d = {2.9: [0.66], 3.3: [0.82, 0.48]}

keys, vals = result = [], []
for k in d:
    for v in d[k]:
        keys.append(k)
        vals.append(v)
```

Comment: I like this one better than mine - and it's probably faster too