# I have a list of lists. I would like to make a new list of lists, but each new list will have the same indices of the old list

Tags: python, list

Imagine my old list is:

```
old = [[card, towel, bus], [mouse, eraser, laptop], [pad, pen, bar]]
```

goal:

```
new = [[card, mouse, pad], [towel, eraser, pen], [bus, laptop, bar]]
```

Things I've tried:

```
new = dict(zip(old[i] for i in range(len(old))))

new = [old[i][0] for i in old] #trying just to get a list of first indices, and then go from there
```

I feel like this is a trivial problem, but I'm having trouble. Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

Also:
Imagine I have another list:

```
list_names = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
```

I would like to set the elements of this list to each one of the new lists:

```
list1 = [card, mouse, pad]
```

and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a matrix in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037566/transpose-a-matrix-in-python)

Comment: For your second question, this would be doing dynamic variable lookup, which is probably not a good idea. Could be achieved with `lists = [locals()[name] for name in list_names]`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, this is the basic usage of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> old = [['card', 'towel', 'bus'], ['mouse', 'eraser', 'laptop'], ['pad', 'pen', 'bar']]
>>> zip(*old)
[('card', 'mouse', 'pad'), ('towel', 'eraser', 'pen'), ('bus', 'laptop', 'bar')]
```

I can't understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** If you want reach your first goal in one line and want to use list comprehensions try:

```
old = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
new = [[sublist[i] for sublist in old ] for i in (0,1,2)]
```

leads to `new = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`.

**Method 2:** However you can also use the `zip`-function like this:

```
new = [list for list in zip(*old)]
```

will lead to `new = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]`. Note that this is a list of tuples as opposed to the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the input everyone!
zip(*old) worked like a charm, though I'm not entirely sure how...

For the second problem, I used this: (I know this is not a good solution, but it worked)

```
for name in range(input_num):
    exec(list_names[name] + ' = arranged_list[name]')
```