# Python Read csv files in a column?

Tags: python

Is it possible to read `csv` files in columns instead of rows in python?

e.g. if i have a csv file like this:

```
a b c
1 0 1
1 4 1
```

How would one get a list of `[a,1,1],[b,0,4],[c,1,1]` or something of the sorts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv this answers your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for transpose functionality. To solve your problem,

1. First read csv as rows and create row wise tuples in a list
   ex: `[(a,b,c),(1,0,1),(1,4,1)..]`
2. Transpose above list using any of the solutions present in [Transpose a matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037566/transpose-a-matrix-in-python).

Post transpose , your data will look like `[(a,1,1),(b,0,4)..]`

Answer (score 3):

use `zip(*reader)`.

some.csv

```
a b c 
1 0 1 
1 4 1
```

scrip.py

```
import csv 
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    print zip(*reader)
```

output:

```
[('a', '1', '1'), ('b', '0', '4'), ('c', '1', '1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
# Open file and read lines
input_file = open('filename.csv')
lines = input_file.readlines()

# Create list with n sublists (n - number of columns)
l = [[] for _ in lines[0].split('\t')]

# Fill in sublists
for line in lines:
    for i, column in enumerate(line.split('\t')):    
        l[i].append(column)
```