# Convert csv rows into colum

Tags: python, csv

So I have a csv file that looks like this..

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

And I want to make it look like this..

```
1   2   3
a   b   c
```

I'm at a loss for how to do this with python3, anyone have any ideas? Really appreciate it

Comment: build a 2D array with x and y indices switched? Then save the array. Where is your problem?

Comment: read to a pandas dataframe and transpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037566/transpose-a-matrix-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you reading the csv with pandas? you can always use numpy or pandas transpose

```
import numpy as np
ar1 = np.array([[1,2,3], ['a','b','c']])
ar2 = np.transpose(ar1)

Out[22]: 
array([['1', 'a'],
       ['2', 'b'],
       ['3', 'c']], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `pandas` and `transpose()` is the way to go here. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

input_filename = "path/to/file"

# I am using space as the sep because that is what you have shown in the example
# Also, you need header=None since your file doesn't have a header
df = pd.read_csv(input_filename ), header=None, sep="\s+")  # read into dataframe

output_filename = "path/to/output"
df.transpose().to_csv(output_filename, index=False, header=False)
```

**Explanation**:

`read_csv()` loads the contents of your file into a `dataframe` which I called `df`. This is what `df` looks like:

```
>>> print(df)

    0   1
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
```

You want to switch the rows and columns, and we can do that by calling `transpose()`. Here is what the transposed `dataframe` looks like:

```
>>> print(df.transpose())

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  a  b  c
```

Now write the transposed `dataframe` to a file with the `to_csv()` method. By specifying `index=False` and `header=False`, we will avoid writing the header row and the index column.