# Transpose nested list in python

Tags: python, list

I like to move each item in this list to another nested list could someone help me?

```
a = [['AAA', '1', '1', '10', '92'], ['BBB', '262', '56', '238', '142'], ['CCC', '86', '84', '149', '30'], ['DDD', '48', '362', '205', '237'], ['EEE', '8', '33', '96', '336'], ['FFF', '39', '82', '89', '140'], ['GGG', '170', '296', '223', '210'], ['HHH', '16', '40', '65', '50'], ['III', '4', '3', '5', '2']]
```

On the end I will make list like this:

```
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'.....],
['1', '262', '86', '48', '8', '39', ...],
['1', '56', '84', '362', '33', '82', ...],
['10', '238', '149', '205', '96', '89', ...],
...
...]
```

Comment: In case you list of lists is not square, you can  find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38815389/2521204

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `zip` with `*` and `map`:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*a))
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH', 'III'],
 ['1', '262', '86', '48', '8', '39', '170', '16', '4'],
 ['1', '56', '84', '362', '33', '82', '296', '40', '3'],
 ['10', '238', '149', '205', '96', '89', '223', '65', '5'],
 ['92', '142', '30', '237', '336', '140', '210', '50', '2']]
```

Note that `map` returns a map object in Python 3, so there you would need `list(map(list, zip(*a)))`

Using a `list comprehension` with `zip(*...)`, this would work as is in both Python 2 and 3.

```
[list(x) for x in zip(*a)]
```

---

NumPy way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(a).T.tolist()
[['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH', 'III'],
 ['1', '262', '86', '48', '8', '39', '170', '16', '4'],
 ['1', '56', '84', '362', '33', '82', '296', '40', '3'],
 ['10', '238', '149', '205', '96', '89', '223', '65', '5'],
 ['92', '142', '30', '237', '336', '140', '210', '50', '2']]
```

Comment: wow, this was pretty easy, thank you.I tried make for loop but this are nice solution

Answer (score 3):

Through list comprehension:

```
[[x[i] for x in mylist] for i in range(len(mylist[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
a= np.array(a).transpose().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
row1 = [1,2,3]
row2 = [4,5,6]
row3 = [7,8,9]

matrix = [row1, row2, row3]
trmatrix = [[row[0] for row in matrix],[row[1] for row in matrix],  [row[2] for row in matrix]]
```