# code for split a list of items into list (split function) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function to split the list, 
example

```
def split(*arg):
    row = len(arg[0])
    col = len(arg)
    new = [row * col]
    for i in row:
        for j in col:
            new[j][i] = arg[i][j]
    return new

    # this is method for split the list but it is include errors
```

Desired output:

```
list_a = [(1,2,3),(8,9,10),(100,20,15)]

split (list_a) 
[(1,8,100),(2,9,20),(3,10,15)]
```

Comment: based on expected output I'd say you are trying to find the [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Transpose nested list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444338/transpose-nested-list-in-python).

However, you want a list of tuples as the result, so we don't even need a list comprehension. Just

```
list_a = [(1,2,3),(8,9,10),(100,20,15)]

zip(*list_a)  # Python 2
# or
list(zip(*list_a))  # Python 3
# [(1, 8, 100), (2, 9, 20), (3, 10, 15)]
```

This uses [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and the built-in [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 0):

based on the desired output it seems you are trying to find the [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) so you could do it with numpy like this:

```
import numpy
list_a = [(1,2,3),(8,9,10),(100,20,15)]
transpose_a = numpy.transpose(list_a)
print(transpose_a)
#or
#print(list(transpose_a))
```

But your `split` is malfunctioning for a few reasons reasons:

- you are using [*arg perameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) but not unpacking the argument so you need to call it like `split(*list_a)`
- `new = [row * col]` is creating a new list with one item instead of a [two dimensional list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397141/how-to-initialize-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python).
- you are [iterating over integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941288/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable) instead of using `range(row)` and `range(col)`.
- row and col need to be swapped: `row = len(arg)` and `col = len(arg[0])` since you use row as first dimension and col as second.

Although it occurs to me that this is what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is designed to do so maybe you just need to use that instead.