# python: create numpy array from dictionary, where key is coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary of the following form:

```
{(2, 2): 387, (1, 2): 25, (0, 1): 15, (2, 1): 12, (2, 6): 5, (6, 2): 5, (4, 2): 4, (3, 4): 4, (5, 2): 2, (0, 2): 1}
```

where key represents coordinates to the matrix, and value is actual value to be added at the coordinates.

At the moment I create and populate matrix in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

def build_matrix(data, n):
   M = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=np.float64)
   for key, val in data.items():
      (row, col) = key
      M[row][col] = val
```

Is there a way to do it shorter, using numpy'a API? I looked at `np.array()`, `np.asarray()` bit none seem to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest version given `n` and the input dictionary itself seems to be -

```
M = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=np.float64)
M[tuple(zip(*d.keys()))] = list(d.values())
```

That `tuple(zip(*d.keys()))` is basically transposing nested items and then packing into tuples as needed for [`integer-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) into NumPy arrays. [`More info on transposing nested items`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444338/).

**Generic case**

To handle generic cases, when `n` is not given and is required to generated based on the extents of the keys alongwith dtype from dictionary values, it would be -

```
idx_ar = np.array(list(d.keys()))
out_shp = idx_ar.max(0)+1
data = np.array(list(d.values()))
M = np.zeros(shape=out_shp, dtype=data.dtype)
M[tuple(idx_ar.T)] = data
```

Comment: thanks for feedback. Could you explain the meaning of `*list(d.keys()` ?  So I understand that `list()` turns its input into a list, given the input is iterative, but what does `*` do?

Comment: @Mark Added some comments on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `scipy`, what you've basically created is a sparse [`dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) (**D**ictionary **o**f **K**eys)

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

out = dok_matrix((n, n))
out.update(data)
out = out.todense()
```