# Extract a column from a list of rows with Python

Tags: python, transpose

I have the following dataset, which is a series of rows stored as nested lists:

```
[['John', '35', 'UK'],
['Emma', '43', 'UK'],
['Lucy', '25', 'AU']]
```

(rows are always the same length)

I need to return `'UK', 'AU'` as an iterable (indifferent to ordering).

Is there a one-liner that returns the unique values contained in the third column, and which is simpler than this?

```
set(list(map(list, zip(*l)))[2])
```

(Ref: [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/python-list-of-lists-transpose-without-zipm-thing][1]))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change in you own code:

Python 3.x:

```
set(list(zip(*l)[2]))
```

Python 2.x:

```
set(zip(*l)[2])
```

**Demo:**

```
l=[['John', '35', 'UK'],['Emma', '43', 'UK'],['Lucy', '25', 'AU']]
set(list(zip(*l)[2]))
{'AU', 'UK'}
```

Comment: Right! I tried that initially, but you need to convert zip's output to either list or tuple for each to be subscriptable. Otherwise it throws an exception.

Comment: @bsuire which python version are you using

Comment: 3. I didn't thought that would be of importance here, but I guess zip and map behave slightly differently depending on the version of Python.

Comment: @bsuire yes :) they are in python 2.x `set(zip(*l)[2])` will work

Answer (score 4):

You can use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> L = [['John', '35', 'UK'],
['Emma', '43', 'UK'],
['Lucy', '25', 'AU']]
>>> set([i[2] for i in L])
set(['AU', 'UK'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l = [['John', '35', 'UK'],
         ['Emma', '43', 'UK'],
         ['Lucy', '25', 'AU']]
>>> set(element[-1] for element in l)
('AU', 'UK')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([['John', '35', 'UK'],
                ['Emma', '43', 'UK'],
               ['Lucy', '25', 'AU']])

unique = np.unique(arr[:,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the actually requirements of bsuire are more complicated in practice, so I recommend to use pandas to process such requirements, it's more powerful and flexible.

so, how to use pandas in this case:

```
In [17]: import pandas as pd

In [18]: a = [['John', '35', 'UK'],
   ....: ['Emma', '43', 'UK'],
   ....: ['Lucy', '25', 'AU']]

In [19]: b = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [20]: b
Out[20]:
      0   1   2
0  John  35  UK
1  Emma  43  UK
2  Lucy  25  AU

In [21]: b[2].unique()
Out[21]: array(['UK', 'AU'], dtype=object)

In [22]:
```

Comment: thanks!  I should really look into Panda to gain in flexibility for manipulating data. Is Panda also the go to Python module for performing SQL-like aggregation queries?

Comment: for one, pandas support read sql query; for another, pandas really support sql-like aggregation queries, check here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html   , trust me, if you use python do do data science related work, ipython, pandas, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, seaborn, mpld3. etc are the best arms you need