# Transposing a list of lists in python

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

Why does this code doesn't transpose the list of list

```
import sys
t = input()
for k in range(t):
  n,m = [int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split()]
  A = [[None]*m]*n
  B = [[None]*n]*m
  for l in range(n):
    A[l] = raw_input().strip().split()
  for j in range(m):
    for i in range(n):
    B[j][i] = A[i][j]

  print B
```

I know there are better methods to transpose a matrix but why does this doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/python-list-of-lists-transpose-without-zipm-thing?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
A = [[None]*m]*n
B = [[None]*n]*m
```

with

```
A = [[None for x in range(m)] for x in range(n)]
B = [[None for x in range(n)] for x in range(m)]
```

Why?

```
>>> l = [2]*5
>>> l
[2,2,2,2,2]
>>> [id(value) for value in l]
[26089400, 26089400, 26089400, 26089400, 26089400]
```

Can you see what happened there? 
There's just one copy in memory holding a value '2'. All list elements are pointing to that same memory location holding the value '2'.

So, when you do:

```
A = [[None]*m]*n
```

you are creating a 2d array with elements pointing to the same memory location. **Changing one of them, changes the value stored at that common memory location, hence changes value stored by all the elements!**

That is why the program didn't work.

Read more about how all this works in Python, in detail, here: 
http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/