# Place a value in the last row of a list of lists python

Tags: python, list

I am creating Connect 4 in Python. I am new to programming. I have created a board using the below code

```
row = 6

col = 7

board = [[' ']*col for i in range(row)]

for x in board:
    print(x)
```

How can I place a counter in one of the columns and have it goes to the last row? For example, placing it in column 1 will go to x:y index [5:1].

I will be doing this game in OOP, but for now I just want to get a working game.

Comment: Well, forget lists of lists for a moment. Given a list (that's not empty), how do you get at its last element?

Comment: You may find it easier to represent the state of a Connect 4 board as a list of columns, rather than a list of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm pretty new to programming, how would i represent the list as columns @ChrisMartin

Comment: `board = [[' ']*row for i in range(col)]`. You can also [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) the structure when you want it the other way (such as for printing it).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function len(mylist) it will return the length of mylist. Thus use len(mylist)-1 to get the index for the last element because lists are 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

The following will put an `X` in the third position of the last row:

```
row = 6

col = 7

board = [[' ']*col for i in range(row)]

for x in board:
    print(x)
print(board)

board[-1][2] = 'X'
print(board)
```

In Python, the `list[-1]` syntax identifies the last element in a list. `list[-2]` the second to last, etcetera. The position in the list is referred to as the `index`.

Also, remember that Python considers the first element to be list[0], so that in this case, `board[-1]` is the index of the last list in `board`, and `board[-1][2]` is the index of 3rd element of that list.

So what we're doing here is placing an `X` in the element with `index` 2, in the list with `index` -1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and change the last row [-1] and first column [1] this way:

```
board[-1][1] = counter
```

You might want to try the module numpy and change counter to an int value if required. A move by player two would be:

```
import numpy as np
board =  np.zeros((6, 7))
board[-1][1] = 2
```