# selecting specific part of array

Tags: python, arrays

Lets say I have an array

```
a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
     [[5, 6], [7, 8]], 
     [[9, 10], [11, 12]],
     [[13, 14], [15, 16]],
     [[17, 18], [19, 20]]]
```

At the end I would like an array

```
b = [[[5, 6]],[[9, 10]]]
```

I thought that

```
b = a[1:3][0:1]
```

would work. But from that i get

```
b=[[[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of matrix manipulation, you should consider using `numpy`, which lets you do slices like this much more naturally

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider marking the correct answer as correct. Best of luck!

Comment: I do also use `numpy` . But how would it change things in this example?

Comment: @user3527668 because you don't have a any arrays here, only `list` objects. `list` objects do not have dimensions, what you essentially want is multi-dimensional slicing, which `numpy.ndarray` supports.

Comment: So note, if you did `import numpy; arr = numpy.array(a); print(arr[1:3,0:1])`

Comment: That is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want `[[a[1][0]],[a[2][0]]`? Well, for one, I'd figure out another way of writing your arrays to make them easier to parse (visually and mechanically.) But, in response to your question, I'd use a list comprehension. `[a[i][0] for i in [1,2]]` would work, I believe.

Comment: For list comprehension, `[x[0] for x in a[1:3]]` could be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> b = [[a[1][0],a[2][0]]]
>>> print(b)
[[[5, 6], [9, 10]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also see [the answer to this question about transposing lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/8944057), and do something like:

```
at = list(map(list, zip(*a)))
b = at[0][1:3]
```

Though as someone has mentioned in the comments, if you're going to be doing a lot of matrix manipulation, you'd be better off using NumPy.