# iterating through the list elements inside the dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict = {1:['cup','pen'],2:['one','two'],3:['five']}`in which i have to iterate through the first elements of all the `keys`at first and then the second element.
I have written in below way, but the output in which it,iterates through list `index 0`first and then `index 1`.
Any one help me out to modify the code, so that it can iterate all the list's first element's at first and the second element

```
dict = {1:['cup','pen'],2:['one','two'],3:['five']}
for v in dict.values():
  for i in range (len(v)):
    print v[i]
```

Output of above code:

```
cup
pen
one
two
five
```

but want it in this below way :

```
cup
one
five
pen
two
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [zipped-transpose idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists), zip upto the longest list with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). Then iterate over each item in the sub-lists, filtering out `None` values.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for i in zip_longest(*data.values()):
    for j in filter(None, i):
        print(j)

cup
one
five
pen
two
```

Here, `data` is your input dictionary. Don't use `dict` to name variables, it shadows the builtin class with the same name.

Note that this order is not guaranteed on python versions below python-3.6, since dictionaries are not ordered in these older versions of python.

Final note, for python-2.x, the appropriate function to be used is `itertools.izip_longest`.

---

The output of `zip_longest` looks like this:

```
print(list(zip_longest(*data.values())))
[('cup', 'one', 'five'), ('pen', 'two', None)]
```

These `None` values are inserted in place of missing values due to the "zip longest' behaviour of the function. These `None`s are removed with `filter`.

---

You can use this to get creative using `itertools.chain` and a `print` statement, accomplishing this in one line:

```
from itertools import chain
print(*filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*data.values()))), sep='\n')

cup
one
five
pen
two
```

Re-written a little more clearly:

```
print(
   *filter(                                 # `filter` out None (iterable unpacking)       
        None, 
        chain.from_iterable(                # flatten an iterable of iterables
               zip_longest(*data.values())  # zip-longest transpose
       )
    ), 
    sep='\n'                                # separate unpacked arguments with newline
)
```

---

One more option, <s>for homework submission</s> without `zip_longest`. This just cycles over the keys, popping one element at a time from each list.

```
while any(bool(v) for v in data.values()):
    for k in data:
        try:
            print(data[k].pop(0))
        except IndexError:
            pass

cup
one
five
pen
two
```

This empties `data` of its contents, so you may want to make a copy of your data beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, Even i can filter out the "None" values, but is there any normal way using "for loop" we can iterate ?

Comment: @STripathy The "normal way using for loop" is the very first option I gave you.

Comment: I mean not using "itertools.zip_longest"

Answer (score 3):

You could try converting each list in your dictionary to [`collections.deqeue()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) objects, then popping off the first item in each queue until all queues are empty:

```
from collections import deque

d = {1:['cup','pen'],2:['one','two'],3:['five']}

# convert to deques
lsts = [deque(x) for x in d.values()]

# while lsts still has queues to pop
while lsts:

    # go over all the queues again
    for lst in lsts:

        # if it is not empty, pop it off and print it. 
        if len(lst) > 0:
            print(lst.popleft())

    # only keep queues that are not empty
    lsts = [x for x in lsts if x]
```

Which Outputs:

```
cup
one
five
pen
two
```

Having shown this possible approach, it does require more work to produce what you want, whereas @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer addresses how to do this very easily.

Also note that you don't need to use `collections.deque()` here, you can simply pop from lists instead with `pop()`. I used it for convenience and the `O(1)` `popleft()` function.

The only efficiency issue you can run into here is that `pop(0)` is `O(n)` for lists. One way around this is reversing the lists beforehand, and calling `pop()` instead, which results in `O(1)` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without any external library:

```
dict = {1:['cup','pen'],2:['one','two'],3:['five']}



track={}

for i,ja in dict.items():
    for k,n in enumerate(ja):
        if k not in track:
            track[k]=[n]
        else:
            track[k].append(n)

for k in track.values():
    for m in k:
        print(m)
```

output:

```
cup
one
five
pen
two
```