# Python: How do I iterate through an HTML Element Object with LXML/Requests?

Tags: python, html, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to use LXML & Requests to create a data table from a website. I need both text within a tag and text that's contained within a tag. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="houses">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseNumber" value="107">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseState" value="MT">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseStatus" value="Occupied">
<div class="houseInfo">
    <div class="houseCity">Helena</div>
    <div class="houseArea">Helena Valley</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="houses">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseNumber" value="237">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseState" value="MT">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseStatus" value="Occupied">
<div class="houseInfo">
    <div class="houseCity">East Helena</div>
    <div class="houseArea">Helena Valley</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="houses">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseNumber" value="104">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseState" value="MT">
    <input type="hidden" class="houseStatus" value="Vacant">
<div class="houseInfo">
    <div class="houseCity">Helena</div>
    <div class="houseArea">Helena Valley</div>
</div>
</div>
```

From this, I would like to create a table like this:

```
['107', 'MT', 'Occupied', 'Helena', 'Helena Valley']
['237', 'MT', 'Occupied', 'East Helena', 'Helena Valley']
['104', 'MT', 'Vacant', 'Helena', 'Helena Valley']
```

Using Requests & LXML, I'm trying to iterate through `div class="houses"` to get what I need, but every time I try to print the values, it prints this:

```
['107', '237', '104']
['MT', 'MT', 'MT']
['Occupied', 'Occupied', 'Vacant']
['Helena', 'East Helena', 'Helena']
['Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley']
['107', '237', '104']
['MT', 'MT', 'MT']
['Occupied', 'Occupied', 'Vacant']
['Helena', 'East Helena', 'Helena']
['Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley']
['107', '237', '104']
['MT', 'MT', 'MT']
['Occupied', 'Occupied', 'Vacant']
['Helena', 'East Helena', 'Helena']
['Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley', 'Helena Valley']
```

Here's my partial code:

```
link = "example.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False) 
sourceCode = response.content

htmlElem = html.document_fromstring(sourceCode)
houses = htmlElem.find_class('houses')
for house in houses:
    houseNumber = house.xpath('//input[@class="houseNumber"]/@value')
    houseState = house.xpath('//input[@class="houseState"]/@value')
    houseStatus = house.xpath('//input[@class="houseStatus"]/@value')
```

How do I capture the data in a table as illustrated above? Can I iterate through the houses object in a different way?

UPDATE: @efirvida I've modified the code to the following:

```
link = "example.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False) 
sourceCode = response.content

htmlElem = html.document_fromstring(sourceCode)
houses = htmlElem.find_class('houses')
houseNumber = []
houseState = []
houseStatus = []

for house in houses:
    houseNumber.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseNumber"]/@value'))
    print(houseNumber)
    houseState.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseState"]/@value'))
    houseStatus.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseStatus"]/@value'))

data = map(list, zip(*[houseNumber,houseState,houseStatus]))
```

When I do this, the following prints:

```
[['107', '237', '104']]
[['107', '237', '104'], ['107', '237', '104']]
[['107', '237', '104']], ['107', '237', '104'], ['107', '237', '104']]
```

Comment: vote the answer if its rigth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try transposing the results, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) to understand my code.

```
# create a list with elements
houseNumber = []
houseState = []
houseStatus = []

# append each element to it's list
for house in houses:
    houseNumber.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseNumber"]/@value'))
    houseState.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseState"]/@value'))
    houseStatus.append(house.xpath('//input[@class="houseStatus"]/@value'))


# transpose the lists, and turn into a list of list
data = map(list, zip(*[houseNumber,houseState,houseStatus]))

>>> list(data)
#[['107', 'MT', 'Occupied'], ['237', 'MT', 'Occupied'], ['104', 'MT', 'Vacant']]
```

if you can use it as a tuples, just remove the map

```
#just transpose
data = zip(*[houseNumber,houseState,houseStatus])

>>> list(data)
#[('107', 'MT', 'Occupied'), ('237', 'MT', 'Occupied'), ('104', 'MT', 'Vacant') ]
```