# Python printing a 2d list from top to bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pretty-print

I have a list given:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

and I want to print it like this:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

I tried it with the following code but it will give me always a

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(grid):    
    while j < len(grid[j]):
        if i == len(grid)-1:
            print(grid[i][j])
            j = j + 1
        else:
            print(grid[i][j], end='')
            i = i + 1
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

What can I do?

Comment: Im sorry :D forgot it

Comment: Typo: `len(grid[j]):` should be `len(grid[i]):`

Comment: Why don't you use a `for` loop instead of `while`?

Comment: I don't think your loop will rotate the grid as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the columns so use `zip` to get the columns then concatenate the items using `str.join()` method within a list comprehension to form the lines and finally join the lines with new-line characters.:

```
In [89]: print('\n'.join([''.join(c) for c in zip(*grid)]))

..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Comment: Well this works but I don't understand the syntax of it. Would you explain it to me?

Comment: @user8953265 Updated. For more information I'd suggest you to look into the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Kasramvd is excellent and should remain the accepted answer. But here is an answer that is easier to understand, together with some explanation.

```
for row in zip(*grid):
    print(''.join(row))
```

One problem you have is that your `grid` stores things differently than you want to print them. One printout row is not a row in the `grid` but is rather a column. The standard recipe in Python to swap columns and rows in a 2D list is

```
zip(*grid)
```

Basically, the `*` breaks `grid` into its individual rows, and `zip` stitches them together "sideways" in the way we want.

Now that you have printable rows, you need to stitch together the characters
in each row into a single string without any delimiters between the characters. Pythons `join` method for strings will stitch together the characters, and the string showing before the `join` will be the delimiter. Thus,

```
''.join(row)
```

joins your characters together without any delimiter at all.

The rest of my code should be clear to anyone who has learned Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's the transpose of the 2d list
So

```
import numpy as np
np.array(grid).T.tolist()
```

Out:

```
[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473727