# Transpose strings of lists in python

Tags: python, string, list, transpose

I have a dataset names 'df_list'. First three rows of my list is as below;

```
print(df_list[0]) = ['walter', ' extra', ' is', ' a', ' german', ' award-winning', ' aerobatic', ' pilot', '', ' chief', ' aircraft', ' designer', ' and', ' founder', ' of', ' extra', ' flugzeugbau', ' -LRB-', ' extra', ' aircraft', ' construction', ' -RRB-', '', ' a', ' manufacturer', ' of', ' aerobatic', ' aircraft', ' .']

print(df_list[1]) = ['NN', ' JJ', ' VBZ', ' DT', ' JJ', ' JJ', ' JJ', ' NN', ' ', ' NN', ' NN', ' NN', ' CC', ' NN', ' IN', ' JJ', ' NN', ' -LRB-', ' JJ', ' NN', ' NN', ' -RRB-', ' ', ' DT', ' NN', ' IN', ' JJ', ' NN', ' .']

print(df_list[2]) = ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

What am I trying to have as an output is;

```
df_list[:7] = [('walter', 'NN', 'O'),
               (' extra', ' JJ', 'O'),
               (' is', ' VBZ', 'O'),
               (' a', ' DT', 'O'),
               (' german', ' JJ', 'O'),
               (' award-winning', ' JJ', 'O'),
               (' aerobatic', ' JJ', 'O')]
```

I tried below code that I found here [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) but It didn't work and gave me below result;

```
list(map(list, zip(*df_list)))
```

> df_list[0] = ['walter',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'aaron',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'majda',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'linda',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'craig',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'joseph',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'henrik',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'tony',
>    'JJ',
>    'O',
>    'john',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'larisa',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'jon',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'christian',
>    'JJ',
>    'O',
>    'hussain',
>    'NNP',
>    'O',
>    'italo',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'mausami',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'james',
>    'NNS',
>    'O',
>    'roger',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'herbert',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'arthur',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'emanuelis',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'piet',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'ward',
>    'VB',
>    'O',
>    'eddio',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'carlene',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'presley',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'james',
>    'NNS',
>    'O',
>    'george',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'llewellyn',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'kia',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'james',
>    'NNS',
>    'O',
>    'james',
>    'NNS',
>    'O',
>    'timmy',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'john',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'heddy',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'vester',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'jordon',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'walter',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'john',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'robert',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'ma',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'mark',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'jole',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'samu',
>    'FW',
>    'O',
>    'thambiah',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'cliff',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'harold',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'william',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'sheila',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'tanya',
>    'NN',
>    'O',
>    'ryan',
>    'NN',
>    'O']

To be brief;

```
my_df = [['walter',' extra',' is'],['NN',' JJ',' VBZ'],['O','O','O']]

my_df_output = [('walter',' NN','O'),(' extra',' JJ','O'),(' is',' JJ','O')]
```

Appreciate any support possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "but It didn't work." How so? What error/wrong output did you get?

Comment: Please show a complete sample-df and the complete expected result.

Comment: Did none of these help?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+transpose+dataframe

Comment: @DeepSpace I pasted the output of wrong one. I didn't get any error message.

Comment: @timgeb I pasted a sample of my df in here [https://bpaste.net/show/42ed6b217d70]. I thought the one in the question would be enough as an expected output?

Comment: I don't think you understand. We need a small sample dataframe and the desired output for that example in the question itself. The full dataframes, not printouts of specific rows and not a dataframe with 100+ rows or columns.

Comment: @timgeb I just added another line I hope I got your question correct this time.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the problem.

Comment: Are `my_df` and `my_df_output` really nested lists or pandas dataframes?

Comment: Yes, they are both nested lists not pandas.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> p = list(map(list, itertools.zip_longest(*df_list)))
>>> pprint.pprint(p[:7])
[['walter', 'NN', 'O'],
 [' extra', ' JJ', 'O'],
 [' is', ' VBZ', 'O'],
 [' a', ' DT', 'O'],
 [' german', ' JJ', 'O'],
 [' award-winning', ' JJ', 'O'],
 [' aerobatic', ' JJ', 'O']]
```