# How can I add elements of a list (StringType) to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
list1 = [["A","B","C"],["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]
```

how can I convert this to:

```
["Aa1","Bb2","Cc3"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `join`:

```
list1 = [["A","B","C"],["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]

result = [''.join(s) for s in zip(*list1)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Aa1', 'Bb2', 'Cc3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list` with `map`, the key here is [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

```
list(map(''.join,zip(*list1)))
['Aa1', 'Bb2', 'Cc3']
```