# Joining list of lists by element

Tags: python

I want to join list of lists by element such that

```
lst = [['a','b','c'], [1,2,3], ['x','y','z'], [4,5,6]]
```

becomes

```
res = [['a',1,'x',4], ['b',2,'y',5], ['c',3,'z',6]]
```

I'v tried using list comprehension, concatenate and map, but haven't had any luck with it yet. (New to python)

Comment: the letter in the lst list are char or variable?

Comment: Use `zip` Ex: `print(zip(*lst))`

Comment: @CarloZanocco I edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) (similar question: [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)):

```
>>> lst = [["a","b","c"], [1,2,3], ["x","y","z"], [4,5,6]]
>>> res = [list(zipped) for zipped in zip(*lst)]
>>> res
[['a', 1, 'x', 4], ['b', 2, 'y', 5], ['c', 3, 'z', 6]]
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution that I think about, it was so obvious to use the zip function. This is the best way that you can find to do that! @Andri Már Stefánsson You have the solution here

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks