# Iterating through a nested list to produce min and max values ignoring NoneType

Tags: python, nested-lists

I need to find the min and max values in a transposed nested list,  ignoring any none types.

This the nested list I have:

```py
x = [[1, 20, 50],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [11, 42, 2],
     [7, 32, None]]
```

I am wanting to ignore the None in the third column and would expect to have the following output:

```
min
[1, 6, 2]

max
[11,42,50]
```

I need to do this using the standard python library

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: my idea was to use something like:

min_x = [min(col) for col in zip(*list)]

Comment: But I get a type error. If I create a new nested list with the None removed then I cant figure out a way to find the min/max for the last col

Comment: [Transpose the nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) and remove the `None`s from each column before taking the `min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure python solution:

```
In [16]: x = [[1, 20, 50],
    ...:      [5, 6, 7],
    ...:      [11, 42, 2],
    ...:      [7, 32, None]]
    ...:

In [17]: [min((y for y in x if y is not None), default=None) for x in zip(*x)]
Out[17]: [1, 6, 2]

In [18]: [max((y for y in x if y is not None), default=None) for x in zip(*x)]
Out[18]: [11, 42, 50]
```

Note that for `[[None]]` the code above returns `[None]` as there are neither no min nor max elements. If you want this code to raise an exception just remove `default=None`. If you want to exclude `None` from the resulting list just wrap with a list comprehension like `[z for z in (...) if z is not None]`

---

Numpy solution with casting to float to automatically convert None to nan:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: a = np.array(
    ...:     [[1, 20, 50],
    ...:      [5, 6, 7],
    ...:      [11, 42, 2],
    ...:      [7, 32, None]],
    ...:     dtype=np.float)
    ...:

In [14]: np.nanmin(a, axis=0).astype(np.int)
Out[14]: array([1, 6, 2])

In [15]: np.nanmax(a, axis=0).astype(np.int)
Out[15]: array([11, 42, 50])
```