# Transpose ND list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, transpose, opencv

1.I use `cv2.imread` to read a big image in numpy array (1234*1624*3)

2.I use `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage` to transform it to (1,3,1234,1624) numpy array

3.I use `tolist()` to transform it to a 4D list in lists

My Problem:

How to transpose this list's axis

from (1,3,1234,1624) to (1,1234,1624,3)?

I tried `np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 3, 1))` first then do the `tolist()`, but it appears to be very slow. Therefore, I want to transpose in the list form.

I've checked the question below it seems fast but can only transpose 2D list
[Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists/35100286)

Much appreciated!!

Update:

I have a list named temp.

`len(temp)=1`
`len(temp[0])=3`
`len(temp[0][0])=1234`
`len(temp[0][0][0])=1624`

and I want to transpose its axis to

`len(temp)=1`
`len(temp[0])=1234`
`len(temp[0][0])=1624`
`len(temp[0][0][0])=3`

How to do with `temp1=list(map(list, zip(*temp))`?

Comment: Use the idiomatic expression `zip(*zip(*items))`

Comment: I tried `temp1=list(map(list, zip(zip(*temp))))` but doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry I understood it wrongly, the double zip trick work for 1-level nesting iterators only. I think NumPy is the fastest. Why do you need to convert it to `list`?

Comment: I need to send the request in Json format to Tensorflow serving. I've found `ndnumpy (1,3,1234,1624).tolist()` is much faster than `ndnumpy (1,1234,1624,3).tolist()`

Comment: (1,3,1234,1624) is the shape of ndnumpy array

Comment: That array transpose, `np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 3, 1))` should be fast, since it makes a view, not a copy.  Doing a `tolist()` on the may be a bit slower (than a `tolist` on `image`), because it probably involves a copy.  But it should be easier and faster than trying to do the equivalent transpose with lists.

Comment: I'm familiar with the `zip*` idiom for transposing a simple nested list, I'd have experiment to come up with an equivalent for this 4d nesting (3d actually since we can ignore the first size one dimension).  Even with that I'd probably be testing my results against the array version, which is easy to understand.

Comment: `np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 3, 1))` is very fast. However, Doing a `tolist()` on a `(1,1234,1624,3)` numpy array takes 5 time more than a `tolist()` on a `(1,3,1234,1624)` numpy array on my machine.

Comment: Making a nested list with that small size 3 inner most will be costly how ever you do it.  You'll have a million size 3 liats, and pointers to each.

Comment: @hpaulj do you mind sharing your code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done numpy-less and purely functional but it's not pretty:

```
from itertools import starmap, repeat

a = np.ones((1,3,1234,1624)).tolist()
b = list(map(list, map(map, repeat(list), map(starmap, repeat(zip), starmap(zip, a)))))
np.shape(b)
# (1, 1234, 1624, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `np.ones((1,3,1234,1624)).tolist()`+`list(map(list, map(map, repeat(list), map(starmap, repeat(zip), starmap(zip, a)))))` takes only half of the time of `np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 3, 1))`+`tolist()` on my machine! That's a lot!

Comment: However, I'm a little confused about how does those map and zip works. Is it possible for you to simply explain if i want to generalize to other shape N-D list?

Comment: @BillHuang I'm afraid this is about as far as I am able to push it. I don't think it generalizes well (expressions just become longer and longer). As for explanation. We can only swap adjacent axes with `zip`, so we have to construct the shuffle we want from such swaps. The swaps look like: swap axes 0 and 1: zip(*a) ; swap axes 1 and 2: starmap(zip, a) ; swap axes 2 and 3: map(starmap, repeat(zip), a) etc. In Python3 all those return generators, so we have to force lists in an additional step.

Comment: So begining --> `(1, 3, 1234, 1624)`
Next,`starmap(zip, a)` --> `(1, 1234, 3, 1624)` (swap axes 1 and 2)
Next,`map(starmap, repeat(zip), starmap(zip, a)))`-->`(1, 1234, 1624, 3)`(swap axes 2 and 3)

Am I understanding this correctly? Then what's `map(list, map(map, repeat(list), )` doing outside?
Thank you very much for your reply! @PaulPanzer

Comment: @BillHuang yes, that's correct so far. As I said, these do not create lists but generators. A generator is something like a "suspended for loop", you have to loop through it or map it to a list or tuple, otherwise it does nothing. As with the swaps, these generators are created at different depths of nesting, which is why we have to administer the `list` cast through `map`s and nested `map`s.