# How to print a jagged array vertically?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array like this:

```
arr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
       ['i', 'j']]
```

How to get the output like this?

```
str = aei bfj cg dh
```

So basically, how to print a jagged array vertically?

Comment: With `itertools.zip_longest`

Comment: Particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/35100286/5218354

Comment: I believe that would be called printing the array _horizontally_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to stride column-wise, and then `filter` out when `None` is encountered. Then pass that as a generator expression through `str.join` to create a single space-delimited string.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ' '.join(''.join(filter(None, i)) for i in itertools.zip_longest(*arr))
'aei bfj cg dh'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for row in zip_longest(*arr, fillvalue=''):
    print(' '.join(row))
```