# Convert index to column names

Tags: python

I am trying to take the index of a dataframe and swap it with the column header names.

For example:

```
Index Header1 Header2 Header3                    Index   0  1  2  3

0                                                Header1

1                                       ===>     Header2

2                                                Header3

3
```

Comment: Are you looking to something similar to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), which will swap the rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to swap the labels without transposing the values in the dataframe (assuming it is square):

```
df.index, df.columns = df.columns, df.index
```