# How to print each element of a list of lists of variable length as a column in python?

Tags: python

Consider the following list:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

How can I achieve this printing pattern?

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

More specifically, how can I do it in general for any number of elements in `L` while assuming that all the nested lists in `L` have the same length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for x in zip(*L):
    print(*x)
```

**Output:**

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Answer (score -1):

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

    
for i in zip(*L):        
    print(*i)
```

Produces:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

(*i) says to do all of the arguments inside of i, however many there are.

Comment: That code doesn't produce that output. Maybe you forgot to `zip(*L)`, but that's already covered in [deadshot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63528156/4518341).

Comment: Yeah my bad, fixed.