# Reading a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv

Good morning everyone.

I have a csv file with 3 columns: product, quantity and price.

I want to create 3 list, one for each column.

I try with the following code, but this create a list for each row instead of a list for each column. Any idea, please??

Thanks in advance :)

```
import csv
with open ("./02_CSV_data.csv","r") as myCSV:
   contenido=csv.reader(myCSV)
   for i in contenido:
      print(i)
```

Comment: Why do you want to put them in separate lists? It's much easier to work with data if you keep the related information together.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

Append each element of the list to the appropriate list.

```
import csv

products = []
quantities = []
prices = []

with open ("./02_CSV_data.csv","r") as myCSV:
   contenido=csv.reader(myCSV)
   for i in contenido:
        products.append(i[0])
        quantities.append(i[1])
        prices.append(i[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are trying to do this with `csv` but [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started) can do this easily :

Install Pandas using `pip`:

```
pip install pandas
```

Code to convert csv columns to list:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'path/of/csv/file.csv')

list1 = df['col_name_1'].to_list()
list2 = df['col_name_2'].to_list()
list3 = df['col_name_3'].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the read in rows - this is less efficient then Barmars solution though - it creates the big list of data and then creates 3 smaller lists from it instead of only creating the smaller lists:

Create data:

```
with open ("./02_CSV_data.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""
1,1a,1b
2,2a,2b
3,3a,3b
""")
```

Read data as rows:

```
import csv

data = []
with open ("./02_CSV_data.csv","r") as myCSV:
   contenido = csv.reader(myCSV)
   for i in contenido:
       if i: # avoid empty rows
           data.append(i)
```

Extract colums using zip():

```
products, quantities, prices = map(list, zip(*data))

print(products)
print(quantities)
print(prices)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1a', '2a', '3a']
['1b', '2b', '3b']
```