# Transpose an already flattened square matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, transpose

Given a square matrix represented as a list of lists, you can [transpose it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/13386979):

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> l_T = list(map(list, zip(*l)))
>>> l_T

[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

You can then flatten a list of lists using a list comprehension:

```
>>> v = [i for j in l for i in j]
>>> v_T = [i for j in l_T for i in j]

>>> v
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> v_T
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

My question is, **is there a way to take the flattened list version of a square matrix, and rearrange it so it becomes the transposed version?** Here, that would be to get from `v` to `v_T` without going back through a list of lists.  I have tried to map out the relationship between the matrix position and the list indices, but I am not seeing the pattern, let alone one that would generalize to lists of any (square) length.

In order to try to avoid any XY problems: my original goal was to be able to take some simple list of list matrices and iterate over them in different ways (i.e. left>right then top>bottom versus top>bottom then left>right).  And if your starting point is `l`, then it is easy to just create the transpose and unpack.  But I am imagining you have the flattened matrix (`v`) as a starting point, and you want to compute `v_T` directly.  So I am really more curious about that algorithm now, and how to do so in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by finding the square root of the lists' length, and take slices of the list iteratively, starting on different lags until you've sliced all *columns* (or what would be the columns in a transposed 2D array):

```
def transpose_flat_list(l):
    n = int(len(l)**.5)
    return [v for i in range(n) for v in l[i::n]]
```

For the shared example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

transpose_flat_list(l)
# [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

This could easily be done in `NumPy` too by reshaping and raveling in fortran order as:

```
def transpose_flat_list_numpy(l):
    n = int(len(l)**.5)
    return np.array(l).reshape(n,n).ravel('F').tolist()

transpose_flat_list_numpy(l)
# [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```