# How to make strings in .txt file into columns?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make 3 columns in my .txt file to make it easier to read. This is the code:

```
file_out = open("Assignment1_Part1.txt", "w")
file_out.write(str(x) + str(fx(x, a)), + str(fx1(x, a)))
file_out.close()
```

Where x,fx, and fx1 each contain a ton of different values. I want the first value of x to line up with the first value of fx and fx1, however in the .txt file whats happening is all of the x values are typed out first, followed by all the fx, followed by all fx1, like so:

(x)(x)1(x)2
(fx)(fx)1(fx)2
(fx1)(fx1)1(fx1)2

whereas I want it to look like this:

(x)  (fx)   (fx1)

(x)1 (fx)1  (fx1)1

(x)2 (fx)2  (fx1)2

And so on. Thanks in advance!

edit: whole code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining Functions ----



def fx(x, a):
    return np.sin(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x)


def gx(x, a):
    return a*(x)**(a-1) - (1/a)*x**((1/a) - 1) + a


def fx1(x, a):
    return gx(x, a) * (np.cos(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x))


# NR Method ----


def NR(x, function, deriv):
    return x - function/deriv


# Creating x values and defining a ----
x = np.arange(0.00, 5, 0.01)
a = 0.4 + (0223.0 / 25000.0)


# np.column_stack joins two arrays to make a table
ar1 = np.column_stack((x, fx(x, a)))
print(ar1)

plt.plot(x, fx(x, a))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
#plt.savefig("part1")
plt.savefig('part1')
# ar2 = np.column_stack((ar1,fx1(x,a)))
# print(ar2)

file_out = open("Assignment1_Part1.txt", "w")
file_out.write(str(x)+str(fx(x, a))+str(fx1(x, a)))
file_out.close()
```

Edit 2:
Sorry for not making this clear, but the txt file is huge, like 240 lines, the assignment is the plot of a graph so it contains every x value and y value on the graph. This would make adding a newline after each value impossible

Comment: can you send the whole code and data you try to write

Comment: is there a reason why you dont use pandas for this? would be much easier and more efficient, save as csv

Comment: Suggestion: Write a comma separated file which is easily parsed, read by tools, rather than adding (unnecessary) whitespace to the file.  Chances are, you’ll regret the whitespace later, and thank yourself for the commas!  This is based on the principal of a flat file format.

Comment: also I suggest using `with` statement for opening files. look it up its useful

Comment: @Matiiss will edit whole code in

Comment: Couldn't you just add a linebreak character at the end of each line?

Comment: Possibly related: [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Comment: so as I understand its not a list

Comment: I suggest you learning how to get that data into a csv

Comment: @Matiiss Yep its not a list, and I'll get on that now, thank you!

Comment: @morgy2190 I posted an answer go check it out (output may not be the **most** readable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here ya go its in gonna be in `.txt` file now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining Functions ----



def fx(x, a):
    return np.sin(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x)


def gx(x, a):
    return a*(x)**(a-1) - (1/a)*x**((1/a) - 1) + a


def fx1(x, a):
    return gx(x, a) * (np.cos(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x))


# NR Method ----


def NR(x, function, deriv):
    return x - function/deriv


# Creating x values and defining a ----
x = np.arange(0.00, 5, 0.01)
a = 0.4 + (0223.0 / 25000.0)


# np.column_stack joins two arrays to make a table
ar1 = np.column_stack((x, fx(x, a)))
# print(ar1)

plt.plot(x, fx(x, a))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
#plt.savefig("part1")
plt.savefig('part1')
# ar2 = np.column_stack((ar1,fx1(x,a)))
# print(ar2)
temp = []
c = 0
for i in range(len(fx(x, a))):
    str = f'{x[c]}, {fx(x, a)[c]}, {fx1(x, a)[c]}'
    temp.append(str)
    c += 1
with open("Assignment1_Part1.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would do it like this, not with file open

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(0.00, 5, 0.01)

a = 0.4 + (0223.0 / 25000.0)
def fx(x, a):
    return np.sin(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x)


def gx(x, a):
    return a*(x)**(a-1) - (1/a)*x**((1/a) - 1) + a


def fx1(x, a):
    return gx(x, a) * (np.cos(x**a - x**(1 / a) + a * x))

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["x","fx","fx1"])
df['x'] = data
df['fx'] = fx(df['x'],a)
df['fx1'] = fx1(df['x'],a)
print(df)

df.to_csv("file_name.csv")
```

The dataframe will look like this (you can select what the delimiter between data is by `sep` param in `to_csv`, default is comma):

> ```
>         x        fx        fx1
> 0    0.00  0.000000        inf
> 1    0.01  0.155553   6.545237
> 2    0.02  0.208523   4.429984
> 3    0.03  0.247846   3.529117
> 4    0.04  0.280304   3.001404
> ..    ...       ...        ...
> 495  4.95 -0.895714  10.722176
> 496  4.96 -0.763377  15.623705
> 497  4.97 -0.586145  19.655121
> 498  4.98 -0.374017  22.565874
> 499  4.99 -0.139202  24.166720
> ```

Comment: Nice answer, clean. Upvote for CSV and steering well clear of arbitrary whitespace!

Comment: actually you should try with the actual code (definitions) because it returns arrays or sth

Comment: Edited it with actual OPs functions and data, there is no change in my part of code tho, will work just as fine :)

Answer (score 0):

(fake?) data

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0.001, .1, 0.01)
a = 0.4 + (0223.0 / 25000.0)
```

Use zip to transpose the results of the three function calls.

```
data = zip(x,fx(x,a),fx1(x,a))
```

Create a list of strings from that data and write to a file

```
with open(the_file,'w') as f:
    f.writelines(f'{x},{y},{z}\n' for (x,y,z) in data)
```