# List Comprehension with sum of elements in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[['State', 'Gas', 'Air', 'Food', 'Party'],
 ['Alabama', 4802982, 9, 213068.0, 52419.02],
 ['Alaska', 721523, 3, 31618.0, 663267.26],
 ['Arizona', 6412700, 11, 144393.0, 113998.3],
 ['Arkansas', 2926229, 6, 209159.0, 53178.62],
 ['California', 37341989, 55, 394608.0, 163695.57],
 ['Colorado', 5044930, 9, 184289.0, 104093.57],
 ['Connecticut', 3581628, 7, 45744.0, 5543.33],
 ['Delaware', 900877, 3, 13849.0, 2489.27],
 ['District of Columbia', 0, 3, 3418.0, 68.34],
 ['Florida', 18900773, 29, 271024.0, 65754.59],
 ['Georgia', 9727566, 16, 271920.0, 59424.77],
 ['Hawaii', 1366862, 4, 9662.0, 10930.98],
 ['Idaho', 1573499, 4, 98649.0, 83570.08],
 ['Illinois', 12864380, 20, 305872.0, 57914.38]]
```

I want to create a list called total, which contains the sum of the data elements in this order: sum of states’ gas, sum of states’ air, sum of states’ food, and sum of states’ party. Obviously avoiding the column name list at the top of the list and also the states' names. I have tried multiple things, but this is what I think is leading me in the right direction so far:

```
total = [sum(x) for x in statesData[x]]
```

Comment: If you have pandas, this is a lot simpler: just use `df.sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to use `numpy`, this can be solved with one line of code

```
data = [['State', 'Gas', 'Air', 'Food', 'Party'],
 ['Alabama', 4802982, 9, 213068.0, 52419.02],
 ['Alaska', 721523, 3, 31618.0, 663267.26],
 ['Arizona', 6412700, 11, 144393.0, 113998.3],
 ['Arkansas', 2926229, 6, 209159.0, 53178.62],
 ['California', 37341989, 55, 394608.0, 163695.57],
 ['Colorado', 5044930, 9, 184289.0, 104093.57],
 ['Connecticut', 3581628, 7, 45744.0, 5543.33],
 ['Delaware', 900877, 3, 13849.0, 2489.27],
 ['District of Columbia', 0, 3, 3418.0, 68.34],
 ['Florida', 18900773, 29, 271024.0, 65754.59],
 ['Georgia', 9727566, 16, 271920.0, 59424.77],
 ['Hawaii', 1366862, 4, 9662.0, 10930.98],
 ['Idaho', 1573499, 4, 98649.0, 83570.08],
 ['Illinois', 12864380, 20, 305872.0, 57914.38]]

sum_states = np.sum(np.array(data)[1:,1:].T.astype(np.float16),axis=1)
```

---

To solve this problem with `list-comprehension`, transpose the list of lists with `map(list,zip(*data))` will be a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/8366805)

```
[sum(item[1:]) for item in list(map(list, zip(*data)))[1:]]
```

Comment: I want to deepen my understanding of list comprehension, that's why I rather do it in the complicated way

Comment: @Yoko It will be intuitive to transpose the list of lists before list comprehension, check out my updated post.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `zip` and `next`:

```
it = zip(*statesData[1:])
next(it) # Pop out the state names

["Total", *(sum(i) for i in it)]
```

Output:

```
['Total', 106165938, 179, 2197273.0, 1436348.0800000003]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously avoiding the column name list at the top of the list and also the states' names.

So, get rid of those first:

```
numbers = [row[1:] for row in data[1:]]
```

> sum of the data elements [columnwise]

So the first thing we need to do is [transpose the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) to swap columns and rows, and then we can sum each row.

```
transposed = # go check the other answer!
total_gas, total_air, total_food, total_party = [sum(column) for column in transposed]
# Alternate spelling:
# total_gas, total_air, total_food, total_party = map(sum, transposed)
# This works because our function only needs one argument, which is an element
# from the transposed list; and because we are unpacking the resulting `map`
# object right away.
```

---

But it seems like your general underlying question is really "how do I get my head around list comprehensions?". In which case, please see [this reference](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Comment: I tried "sums = [sum(row[i+1]) for row in statesData]" and got list index out of range. Can it possibly be fixed to do what I'm looking for? I would rather use a simple primitive approach first

Comment: Where is the `i` value supposed to be coming from?

Comment: based on your answer, I get that that code will not work either.

Comment: You're close. You just need to supply an `i` value in an organized, meaningful way. Think: when you want to get the total gas amount, what should `i` be equal to? How about for the other results? Now, try to think of a way to convert that into iteration, and use an outer list comprehension to manage that. Of course, you also still need to ignore the first row of `statesData`. You can easily do that with just `statesData[1:]`, which you'll notice is a recurring thing in the advice you've been given so far.

Comment: wait... I'm getting a ticklish feeling in my brain... should I have something like row[i][1] ?

Comment: No, you should stick with the `row[i+1]` that you have. Just that `i` *needs to have a value that makes sense*. Please *actually read and answer each of my questions in order*, and only then try to write code.