# How can I extract all columns and diagonal from a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a list of lists, for example:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

I need to get this:

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

And I also need to get the diagonal.
I'd preferably need to do this without importing other libraries.

Comment: so you want to transpose matrix?

Comment: Any reason for not using libraries? This is an easy one liner with numpy transpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists

Comment: Yes, I didn't really know how to word that, but I'd like to do it without using numpy

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]

[list(i) for i in zip(*arr)]
```

output:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

To get the diagonal:

```
[arr[x][x] for x in range(len(arr))]
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 9]
```