# Transponse a list of lists from 2nd element in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, zip, element, transpose

`list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 8, 9, 10]]`

I would like to get to:
`transposed_list = [[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10]]`

In other words, only transpose from the 2nd element in the list, keeping the first element in place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6, 7], [1, 8, 9, 10]]

out = [
    [list_of_lists[i][0]] + list(l)
    for i, l in enumerate(zip(*(l[1:] for l in list_of_lists)))
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 10]]
```