# Is there any way to convert one columns into multiple in python

Tags: python

I have a data which has the following structure in only one column:

```
Datetime stamp 1
Obs1
Obs2
Obs3
Datetime stamp 2
Obs1
Obs2
Obs3
```

I want to convert it like above.
Such that date time will be header and all obs of that specific datetime will become rows of that specific date time stamp

```
Date time stamp 1.     Date time stamp2
Obs1                         Obs1
Obs2.                         obs2
Obs3.                         Obs3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your single column is stored in a list/array, you can make the sub-lists you want like this :

```
lst = ['Datetime stamp 1', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3', 'Datetime stamp 2', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3']

result = []
temp = [lst[0]]
for item in lst[1:]:
    if item.startswith('Datetime'):
        result.append(temp)
        temp = [item]
    else:
        temp.append(item)

result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

output:

```
[['Datetime stamp 1', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3'], ['Datetime stamp 2', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3']]
```

It is now a list of lists which every single elements inside can represent a column for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is the same all along (i.e all splits starts with the string "`Datetime`"), you can get the index of where the string starts with `"Datetime"`, and chose all data between each splits:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(["Datetime stamp 1",
"Obs1",
"Obs2",
"Obs3",
"Datetime stamp 2",
"Obs1",
"Obs2",
"Obs3"])


#Get splits
idx_split =data.str.startswith("Datetime ")
idx_split = idx_split.index[idx_split] # [0,4]


N_COLS = len(idx_split) #number of columns
vals = [0]*N_COLS #Initialize values

#Loop over each split-index and slize data
for i in range(N_COLS-1):
    vals[i] = list(data[idx_split[i]:idx_split[i+1]])
vals[i+1] = list(data[idx_split[-1]:]) #Get the last one

print(vals)
#[['Datetime stamp 1', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3'],
#['Datetime stamp 2', 'Obs1', 'Obs2', 'Obs3']]


#Get the first element from each list and use that as column name
# + remove it
cols = [p.pop(0) for p in vals] 


#The data list is in wrong shape for pandas, use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists to transpose the list to right shape

df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(*vals))),columns = cols)
print(df)

#Datetime stamp 1   Datetime stamp 2
#0  Obs1    Obs1
#1  Obs2    Obs2
#2  Obs3    Obs3
```

Comment: Hello friend , I still have a doubt my data is too large and datetime stamp is an object data type . And the raw data is an text file which I am reading using read.csv .

Comment: what do you mean with "data is too large"? To fit in memory? And do you need to convert the data to "datetime" or..?