# How to loop vertically through a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

This is my code atm:

```
puzzle = [
['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0'],
['1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','1'],
]

#30 1 s

counter1 = 0
counter2 = 0

for a in puzzle:
   b = ''.join(a)
   for search in b:
       if search == '1':
           counter1 = counter1 + 1
       if counter1 > counter2:
           counter2 = counter1

#output should be 3
print(counter1, counter2)
```

Now I am trying to loop vertically through my list. So I can find the highest amount of 1's after each other without a 0 interfering. Starting with counting from the top left. Only I haven't the slightest idea on how to do that.
#output should be 3
Could someone help me out?

Comment: [Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists) the list, and then loop through it again normally.

Comment: [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok thx for the suggestion, I am gonna look at it.

Comment: Shouldn’t the output be 4?

Comment: @Jab Starting fom the top, I shall edit my post, thx for the headsup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would go about it

```
puzzle_new = list(map(list, zip(*puzzle)))
```

puzzle_new will now look like the following:

```
[['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']]
```

This will transpose the puzzle list. You can use the same code that you have for the rest of the logic on puzzle_new

Answer (score 0):

Vectorized NumPy solution <sub><sup>(if I understood your question correctly)</sup></sub>:

```
import numpy as np

puzzle = p = [
['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0'],
['1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','1'],
]

p = np.array(puzzle).astype(int)
np.max(np.cumsum(np.diff(np.cumsum(p, axis=0), axis=0), axis=0), axis=0)
```

which gives the maximum number of consecutive `1`s in each of the columns:

```
array([3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2])
```

**Edit** - solution for the vertically flattened array:

```
import numpy as np

puzzle = p = [
['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
['1','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
['0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','0','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0'],
['1','0','0','0','1','0','1','0','1','0'],
['0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','1'],
]
p = np.array(puzzle).astype(int).flatten(order='F')
[sum(i) for i in np.split(p, np.where(np.diff(p) == 1)[0]+1)]
```

which gives:

```
[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: It is a good solution only thing is that you have to start from the top with the counting. So the 2nd is for example 1 and the 5th is also 1

Comment: @CaptainGuan it's good to add an expected output to the question

Comment: @CaptainGuan take a look at the updated solution. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Could you explain how you got 6 in the output?

Comment: @CaptainGuan you flatten the matrix from the top left side downwards (like you said), split it into groups of contunuous `1`s and `0`s and count the number of `1`s in each group. There is 6 `1`s in one of them.