# I have a Matrix class were I need to implement a function, but I don't know how

Tags: python, function

I need to make a function but do not know how. It is a part of a class matrix if that is important. I have a part code and what it needs to print out but I do not know how to make the function, can anyone help me.

This is the current code

```
m1 = Matrix()
m1.set_matrix( [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,7,6]] )
print(m1)
```

This is the current output

```
[ 1 2 3 4 ][ 5 6 7 8 ][ 9 8 7 6 ]
```

but it needs to be in rows and columns, the matrix is supposed to be 3x4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Comment: What is the function you are looking to implement? The transpose?

Comment: I only want the function to do one thing, to make the matrix look like a normal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in following ways:

1. **Using pandas:** Convert matrix to pandas data-frame.

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,7,6]])
print(m1.T.to_numpy()) # Transpose the rows and columns
```

**Result:**

```
[[1 5 9]
 [2 6 8]
 [3 7 7]
 [4 8 6]]
```

2. **Using Numpy:** Assuming it's a numpy matrix.

```
m = m1.to_numpy()
```

```
print(m)

[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]
 [9 8 7 6]]
```

```
print(m.transpose())

[[1 5 9]
 [2 6 8]
 [3 7 7]
 [4 8 6]]
```