# How to compare between different compartments of a list of lists using only pure python?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list of lists `[[10,2,4.8,90],[7,1,41,5],[3,11,20,2]]` and another empty list of lists `[[],[],[],[]]`.

I want to check the `min` value in each position in each sub-list and add it to it's concordante position in the empty list. So for example compare 10, 7 and 3. It sees that 3 is the lowest in that position, so it adds it to the first position in the empty list. The same for the other items.

For the above example, I would want something like `[[3],[1],[4.8],[2]]`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [transpose operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists), and then use `min()` on each row of the transposed list of lists:

```py
[[min(row)] for row in zip(*data)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[[3], [1], [4.8], [2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! how is it done without `zip` ?

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473782/17769815) instead of `zip()` + unpacking, but it's going to be more verbose.