# how to add elements in the list in python with one loops or without loops or any direct functions

Tags: python, list

I need code to sum lists.
Example: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]. answer be like [2,4,6].
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]] answer: [6,6,6]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to find solutions yourself before asking, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+sum+list+of+lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-add-two-lists-element-wise-in-python) this can work for `n` number of list too and please try first, read docs, and provide relevant resources that you tried or code snippet.

```py
[a+b+c for a,b,c in zip([1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3])]
```

Output: `[6,6,6]`

if you are okay with using packages use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/) and apply it but read it's documentation beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a [transpose operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473679/17769815), and then use `sum()`:

```py
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[sum(sublist) for sublist in zip(*lst)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[2, 4, 6]
```