# I have 3 lists of numbers, how do I make a list which will contain all the numbers by their indexes?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]
```

And I need to write a function that will return this list:
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3 ,6 ,9]
How can I do that?

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment - not judging - but can you at least share what you have tried?

Comment: The answers here may get you started: [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Your lists
list1 = [1, 2, 3] 
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]

new_list = [list1, list2, list3]
new_list = list(map(list, zip(*new_list)))

print(sum(new_list,[])) # Output: [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3 ,6 ,9]
```

> Expalnation:

**Map:**

The `map()` function is used to apply a function on all elements of a specified iterable and return a map object (We can iterate over its elements).
`map()` will take 2 required positional arguments... A function to run against the iterables. and an iterable. ()

**Zip:**

The `zip()` function combines elements of 2 lists with matching indexes into tuples.
`zip()` will take an undefined number of arguments where each argument is an iterable to zip.

The * in the `zip()` function call "unpacks" a list (or other iterable), making each of its elements a separate argument.

**So basically this is what happens:**

You have a list of lists `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

The `zip(*...)` function will make it be `([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])`
Then the `map()` function will get inside of it and will get every first element in each list. so it will go over the first list pick up the number 1 and put it in a list, then it will go to the next list and pick up the number 4 and put it in the list, then it will go to the next list and pick up the number 7 and put it in the list. then it will do it again but this time pick the second element from each list.. `[2,5,8]` and so on...

then it puts each of those lists it created inside a list `[[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3 ,6 ,9]]`

Finally, to unnest the nested list we use the `sum()` function

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "Hope this helps" - It would be  *more* helpful to *explain* the code you have posted and *why* it works. Anyone can just post code they've written (or found on the web). Teaching involves the explanation. *Why* does it work?  That aside, the code is broken ... `l` is not defined.

Comment: You are right :) I edited my answer and tried to explain it as best as I can...

Comment: Nicely explained. Up-voted for the effort you've put into this, and for the efficiency of the solution.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]

final_list = []

for i in range(len(list1)):

    final_list.append(list1[i])
    final_list.append(list2[i])
    final_list.append(list3[i])

print(final_list)
```

this solution works if the lists have the same size.
You make a for loop which allows you to browse every elements in every list.
After that, you just append the elements of each list to the end of you final list

Comment: Tip: Have a look into the `zip` function. It'll become your friend in cases such as this.  [Documentation linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Thank's for the tip, but i think it's easier if the author is a beginner no ?

Comment: Easier, perhaps. However, inefficient. Personally, I believe teaching best-(better)-practices from the beginning, as it's less bad habits to break later. Both are valid solutions.