# Python Assign Multiple Variables with Map Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

With Python, I can assign multiple variables like so:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
print(a)
print(b)
# 1
# 2
```

Can I do something similar with the map function?

```
def myfunc(a):
  return (a+1, a-1)
  
a_plus_one, a_minus_one = map(myfunc, (1, 2, 3))
# or
a_plus_one, a_minus_one = list(map(myfunc, (1,2,3)))

print(a_plus_one)
print(a_minus_one)
```

These attempts give me too many values to unpack error.

Edit:

Desired output is two new lists.

```
a_plus_one = (2, 3, 4)
a_minus_one = (0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding how `map` works. Look at `list(map(myfunc, (1,2,3)))`:

```
[(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)]
```

You want to **transpose** that using `zip`:

```
>>> a_plus_one, a_minus_one = zip(*map(myfunc, (1,2,3)))
>>> a_plus_one
(2, 3, 4)
>>> a_minus_one
(0, 1, 2)
```

For more info: [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473679/4518341)

Comment: May I ask what the * is for in the zip function?

Comment: @siushi It turns an iterable (the `map`) into separate arguments. For more info, check the link, which also has its own link under "Unpacked argument lists".