# I want to do a 2X3 transposition in python but can't

Tags: python

```
matrix = [['*','*','*'],
          ['*','*','*']]
t_matrix = [['*','*'],
            ['*','*'],
            ['*','*']]
print(list(zip(*matrix)))
[('*', '*'), ('*', '*'), ('*', '*')]
```

The above is what happens.
I want the `matrix` to look like `t_matrix`, but it doesn't. How can I do the transposition?

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension to map each tuple to a list.

```
print([[a, b] for a, b in zip(*matrix)])
```

More generally:

```
print([list(x) for x in zip(*matrix)])
```