# Read all columns from text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a text file. I need to read column values to list. My text file looks like this:

```
40 10 5 5
30 20 10 0
30 30 10 5
```

and desired output is

```
(40,30,30),(10,20,30),(5,10,10),(5,0,5)
```

I tried this code

```
def contest(filename):
    contestFile = open(filename,'r')
    contestFileLines=contestFile.readlines()
    startColumn = 0
    contestResult=[]
    for x in contestFileLines:
        contestResult.append(x.split()[startColumn])
        
    contestFile.close()
    print(contestResult)
    
contest("testing.txt")
```

and its output is just

```
['40', '30', '30']
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your need. You wrote the code you needed to do what you want.

Comment: `[startColumn]` is just putting the first column  in the list, not all the columns. Get rid of that. Then at the end of the loop you can transpose the 2-dimensional list to the order that you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists for how to transpose a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading every line into an list, splitting by each space and mapping to an `int`. Then, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/13376511) (which [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested in the comments) to transpose the list of map generators. Just like this:

```
def cols(path):
    rows = []
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            rows.append(map(int, line.split(' ')))
    return list(map(list, zip(*rows)))


print(cols('test.txt'))  # => [[40, 30, 30], [10, 20, 30], [5, 10, 10], [5, 0, 5]]
```

Alternatively, if you need the output as a tuple, just change this line:

```
return list(map(list, zip(*rows)))
```

to

```
return list(map(tuple, zip(*rows)))
```