# Permutation of 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

I would like to be able to generate all unique permutations of a 2d array in python and keep the order.
Let's say I have a 2D matrix `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. Expected result should be a in 8 x 3 in the form
`[[1, 2, 3],`
`[1, 2, 6],`
`[1, 5, 3],`
`[1, 5, 6],`
`[4, 2, 3],`
`[4, 2, 6],`
`[4, 5, 3],`
`[4, 5, 6]]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transpose the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists), and then use `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product

list(map(list, product(*zip(*data))))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6], [1, 5, 3], [1, 5, 6], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 6], [4, 5, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools) method with product would be the most readible way to do this, but since your question is tagged [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), here is how you can do this using only Numpy methods.

#### 1. Permutations without expected order

You can use this method if order is not important for you. This uses `np.meshgrid` and `np.stack` with some `.reshape` to get the permutations you need, minus the order you expect.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

arr = np.array(lst)
np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arr.T),-1).reshape(-1,3)
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 6],
       [1, 5, 3],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

#### 2. Permutations with expected order

Getting the order to work is a bit "hacky" but a small modification over the above array with simple reordering of columns can solve this with pretty much the same code.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
order = [1,0,2]

arr = np.array(lst)[:,order]
np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arr.T),-1).reshape(-1,3)[:,order]
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [1, 5, 3],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 6],
       [4, 5, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```