# In a two-dimensional array, swap elements arranged symmetrically relative to the main diagonal

Tags: python, matrix

Please help me with the solution of the problem: in a two-dimensional array, swap the elements located symmetrically relative to the main diagonal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6y2i.png)

```
def obmen():
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(n-i):
            if n-i+1 < j:
                b = A[i][j]
                A[i][j] = A[n-j+1][n-i+1]
                A[n-j+1][n-i+1] = b
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print('%0.3f'%(A[i][j]), end=' ')
        print()
    return A

A = obmen()
```

Comment: Try to format your question correctly.

Comment: don't post screenshots; just copy&paste an example input and output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can flip rows an columns using zip():

```
# original 5x5 matrix (list of lists):

i = iter(range(10,35))
M = [ list(row) for row in zip((*[i]*5)) ]

print(*M,sep="\n")
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

Transpose using zip():

```
T = [ list(r) for r in zip(*M) ]

print(*T,sep="\n")
[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
[11, 16, 21, 26, 31]
[12, 17, 22, 27, 32]
[13, 18, 23, 28, 33]
[14, 19, 24, 29, 34]
```

Using simple loops, you would append values from each row to the corresponding row in the resulting matrix:

```
T = []
for row in M:
    for col,value in enumerate(row):
        if len(T) == col:
            T.append([])
        T[col].append(value)

print(*T,sep="\n")
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

If you need the transposition to be done "in-place" you can use indexes for the swaps:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i+1,5):
        M[i][j],M[j][i] = M[j][i],M[i][j]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with regular loops?